# Data fixtures for Unit Testing in .NET

Tags: .net, unit-testing, nunit, moq

In ruby on rails one could define data fixtures in yaml files and then load them to execute certain tests, using objects created from those fixtures (using activerecord as the proxy).

I was wondering if there exists something similar for unit testing with Moq & NUnit.

Currently, I initialize objects manually (such as defining a set of existing objects in a storage container) and rely on inheritance to make objects available to various tests. It works, but data is now intermingled with assertion code, and I'd like to split it.

Comment: Do you need *some* data or do you need *specific* data?

Comment: Well, I have test data that I can reuse. I would like a way to say: "This is the data, build me a collection for this type."

Comment: can you post an example in ruby? maybe then I have a 'ahhh' moment

Answer (score 1):

I could not find any C# fixture library either. So I came up with this: https://www.nuget.org/packages/ts.Datafixtures/

I use it to do functional tests against a Database / Entity Framework: Each time a test is run, the database is completely built from scratch, with the required fixtures for the test case. The fixtures are reusable and can depend on other fixtures.

The lib can be used without Entity Framework, but I am not sure if it would make sense for your case.

Moq makes creating stubs very easy, but if you find yourself repeating the same stubs all over, just extract the common code. Unit Tests are just code. It is totally okay to have helper functions, stub classes, extensions or another facility that provides common required test objects.

I am not familiar with NUnit, but most unit test frameworks come with some concept for dataproviders. The will read a collection from a CSV file or similar and run a test with each entry. If this fits your requirements, it is a nice way to go as well.

You could combine this with Moq - use the scalar values from the CSV to instrument your stub objects.

Hope this helps...